# Is there any way to make an HTTP request to my localhost

Tags: android, http

I made a flask app and is running in my localhost:5000. Is there any way to make an HTTP request to it via my android phone. An app or something that's equivalent to curl or httpie?

Comment: If the HTTP server is only running on `localhost` it cannot be accessed from elsewhere.  That's what `localhost` means!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the app is running on some computer other than "your Android phone."  Therefore, you'll need to know the IP-address of that computer (on your local network), so that the Android can properly direct the request to it.  *(Also, there must be no firewalls, etc., in the way ...)*

`localhost`, on any computer, is always "a reference to 'this computer, itself.'"  (Hence, to your Android, "`localhost` is ... *your Android!")*

You need to find the address of the computer that's running the flask app, on your local network, and somehow provide that IP-address to whatever is running on your phone, so that it can direct its request to port #5000 at that address. (For instance, on Linux, the `ifconfig` command will provide this information ...)

Comment: I've actually never associated the localhost to anything other than a computer :). Thanks for that bit. But, ""somehow provide that IP-address to whatever is running on your phone"" is the issue. What's this thing that ought to be running on my android? Do you know of an app or a way to do this painlessly?

Comment: @MAA if you're just trying to test against some endpoint on your service then you don't have to use a different computer/phone. You can use a utility application like postman or just do a curl command from the terminal to hit your local server. Like the answer above says, you'll need to provide the ip address to whatever application is trying to communicate with your server. IF that application also happens to be on the same machine then you can use 127.0.0.1

Comment: MAA: "painlessly?" I dunno. Somehow, your Android must come up with an IP-address. ### Daniel: I concede, and agree with, your point. But it's pretty obvious in this case that the Android and the host must most-certainly be at two different locations on the local network.